# show textbox on button click dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
    <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
           {
           $comment = $row['comment'];
           $username = $row['UserName'];
           $userid1 = $row['UserId'];
           $date = $row['CDate'];
           $ageDate = time_elapsed_string($date);

          ?>

          <div class="jumbotron" style="border:3px solid #2FAB9B; background-color:#68C8C6;">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10">
           <?php echo $comment; ?>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
           <?php echo $ageDate; ?>
           </div>
           </div>
           <br>
            <label>Comment by &nbsp;<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $userid1; ?>"><?php echo $username; ?></a></span></label><br>
            <a id="reply">Reply</a>
            <br>
            <div style="width:63%; display:none; id="replyForm">
            <form action="">
            <textarea cols="100" rows="4"></textarea><br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right">reply</button>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script>
          $(document).ready(function()
          {
            $("#reply").click(function()
            { 
            $("#replyForm").show();
            });
          });
          </script>
           <?php } ?>
```

I m making a comment system in which a comments are being displayed with each comment there is a reply link on click on reply link I want to show the reply textbox and button.The code above is not working.

Comment: `The code above is not working.` - okay, how? Any errors? What's expected and what's happening?

Comment: You may also want to use Classes instead of IDs for your Javascript selectors.

Comment: @SamSwift웃 alert is being displaying only in first record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly close the `style` attribute of your `div`, and use Classes and Attributes for your Javascript selector.

Using Class selectors enable the Javascript to work for multiple rows/records.

The updated Javascript will fetch the value of the `data-role` attribute, i.e. the unique identifier (in this case the `$userid1`); and show the appropriate `replyForm` div.

You also could place the Javascript outside of your loop like so:

```
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
        $comment = $row['comment'];
        $username = $row['UserName'];
        $userid1 = $row['UserId'];
        $date = $row['CDate'];
        $ageDate = time_elapsed_string($date);      
        ?>      
        <div class="jumbotron" style="border:3px solid #2FAB9B; background-color:#68C8C6;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <?php echo $comment; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <?php echo $ageDate; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <label>Comment by &nbsp;<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $userid1; ?>"><?php echo $username; ?></a></span></label><br>
            <a class="reply" data-role="<?php echo $userid1; ?>">Reply</a> <!-- Changed ID to Class and added data-role attributes for multiple rows -->
            <br>
            <div style="width:63%; display:none;" class="replyForm" data-role="<?php echo $userid1; ?>"> <!-- Style attribute closed, changed ID for Class, added data-role attribute -->
                <form action="">
                    <textarea cols="100" rows="4"></textarea><br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right">reply</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
<script>
// UPDATED Javascript, using Class & Attribute selector
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".reply").click(function(){ 
        $('.replyForm[data-role="'+$(this).attr("data-role")+'"]').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @OwaisLatif Glad to help, feel free to accept the answer and upvote!

Answer (score 2):

You are not completing `""` with your css in `div`

Try this:

```
<div style="width:63%; display:none;" id="replyForm">  <!-- Complete "" to the style -->
```

Instead:

```
<div style="width:63%; display:none; id="replyForm">
```

**Updated:**

If it is use only for first record then you have to add class for `anchor`.

Check below:

```
<a id="reply" class="reply">Reply</a>
```

also add class in your `div`.

```
<div style="width:63%; display:none;" class="replyForm" id="replyForm">
```

and then use class in your `jQuery`.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $(".reply").click(function()
     { 
        $(".replyForm").show();
     });
 });
```

Comment: @OwaisLatif Virb's answer is correct, only the way you build your code it's not going to work because you are doing it on an ID. What this does is create multiple comments with the same ID and when their are multiple of the same ID it will only take the first ID encountered. You'll have to work with classes to make it work.